# Testing Angular and Django Rest Framework apps

Tags: django, angular, selenium, django-rest-framework, pytest

Let's say I have a frontend application written in Angular and a backend application written in Django and Django Rest Framework. I created unit tests for backend application (with pytest) and I'm about to create some functional tests for the frontend application. The thing is that the frontend app needs access to the backend app in order to work correctly. I can write some mocks to handle that, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do that.

My question is, what is the best way to handle that? Should I use a single git repo for both applications or maybe a better way is to use two repositories, but then how to handle the tests for frontend application?

I was also thinking about using selenium with pytest, but then I would have to use a single repository. I am a little bit confused and would really use some good advice. Thanks!

Comment: I'd say this is too much opinion-based. I prefer strict separation of frontend and backend (separate repos and versioning), unit tests for Django with pytest, unit tests for Angular with mocha, e2e tests with protractor and mocking the backend's REST API with e.g. json-server. This has several advantages: you can easily test negative scenarios (backend not responded/responded with 500/404/401/whatever), the setup is times faster than spinning up the complete backend, you can easily mock away paid services if your backend queries any etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit tests as the name suggests is testing separate units of the code in isolation. Meaning that it does not have to depend on any other part, else, you wouldn't know if the test is failing for that particular unit or the units it depends on.

As a result, all tests should mock the request to the backend and return valid responses (or invalid, if you're testing for error handling). The same applies to any other external service that the unit depends on.